# Is the value of a country's currency affected by it's economic status?

Tags: currency

I always thought that since US was the best economy in the world, it's currency (`$`) would be the most 'expensive' - i.e holds the most worth all over the globe.

But apparently, swiss francs (`CHF`) are costlier than USD (as of the time of writing, a difference of `10 cents`) however, the economy of Switzerland is nothing comparable to US.

So how does is a currency's worth determined, if it's not based on the host's economy? Like in history, we see people buying bread with a truckload of notes (which happens due to the state's bad economy - like the german mark after WW2) so I assumed it's directly connected to economic growth.

Answer (score 3):

The value of one unit of a country’s currency is just an arbitrary scaling factor — it doesn’t mean anything. When Australia and New Zealand stopped using the pound sterling and set up their own currencies, the value of a unit of their currencies halved overnight, which meant absolutely nothing.

Comment: if it is indeed arbitrary, then say why does one $ = ~70 INR? Wouldn't they want to have a lower ratio so that technically the country is richer?

Comment: @neelg A country’s wealth isn’t money, it’s goods, services, natural resources, etc. You can’t increase those by redenominating your currency. You don’t get taller if you express your height in centimetres rather than inches, even though the number is bigger.

Comment: Another good example of this is the Yen. It's considered one of the 'strongest' currencies in the world, but it is worth less than 1 American penny (< $0.01).